# Looping through input values and putting them in a certain order to put inside an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object

I am trying to grab values from hidden input fields and stick them in an object that I can post to a url through AJAX. I am able to grab the values but not in the order that I need them. I am grabbing the values like this:

```
var music = {};

var album_name = $(".album_name").each(function() {
    music[$(this).attr("value")] = $(this).val();
     // console.log($(this).val());
});
$(".song_title").each(function() {
    music[$(this).attr("value")] = $(this).val();
     // console.log($(this).val());
});
$(".album_image").each(function() {
    music[$(this).attr("value")] = $(this).val();
     console.log($(this).val());
});
```

And the result is coming out like this:

```
{"Album 1":"Album 1","Album 2":"Album 2","Album 3":"Album 3","Album 4":"Album 4","Song 1":"Song 1","Song 2":"Song 2","Song 3":"Song 3","Song 4":"Song 4","thumbnail.png":"thumbnail.png"}
```

Is there anyway to make the object come out in this type of order:

```
{"Album":"Album 1","Song":"Song 1","Image":"thumbnail.png","Album":"Album 2","Song":"Song 2","Image":"thumbnail.png","Album":"Album 3","Song":"Song 3","Image":"thumbnail.png","Album":"Album 4","Song":"Song 4","Image":"thumbnail.png",}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: JS objects by their nature are unordered.

Comment: If you want an order you will need to use an _Array_, be it many _Objects_ in one _Array_ or an _Array_ and an _Object_ which have some relation to eachother

Comment: You could store each album/song set as an array, and then store each array in your object. Then you can just sort the arrays, which would sort it how you want.

Comment: @user2573699, just structure your data like Tim has done below - an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

As Andy pointed out, objects are unordered by nature. However, if you would use a two-dimensional array the values related to '1' can be in the first value as array.

As example:

```
[{"Album":"Album 1","Song":"Song 1","Image":"thumbnail.png"},{"Album":"Album 2","Song":"Song 2","Image":"thumbnail.png"},{"Album":"Album 3","Song":"Song 3","Image":"thumbnail.png"},{"Album":"Album 4","Song":"Song 4","Image":"thumbnail.png"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This slightly differs from what you want to asked for, but if you are able to perhaps you can consider ordering your items in such a way that your JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "Album 1": {
        "Song":"Song 1",
        "Image":"thumbnail.png"
    },
    "Album 2": {
        "Song":"Song 2",
        "Image":"thumbnail.png"
    },
    "Album 3": {
        "Song":"Song 3",
        "Image":"thumbnail.png"
    }
}
```

Then as you iterate through the album name fields, you can grab the data from the corresponding song and image fields to add to the array.

```
var album_name = $(".album_name").each(function(a,b) {
    music[$(b).attr("value")] = $(b).val();
    music[$('.song_title')[a].attr("value")] = $('.song_title')[a]).val();
    music[$('.album_image')[a].attr("value")] = $('.album_image')[a]).val();
});
```

Mind you, this solution entirely depends on how these elements are rendered to the screen.  As long as they are rendered in the order we are grabbing them (1st album, 1st song, 1st image, s2nd album, ...) then we are good.

Comment: That wasn't exactly what I needed but I found this way gets me what I needed:

Comment: Sorry was there supposed to be a link?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different considerations here.

- iterating over JS object properties (`for (x in obj){...}`) doesn't guarantee any particular order
- the documentation for the jQuery `each()` method doesn't say how it iterates over properties, although if the object is array-like (has a `length` property), it will be treated as an array and presumably return the numbered keys in order
- DOM collections generally *do* have a defined order; for example `document.getElementsByClassName('album_name')` will return an array-like object containing the required elements in the same order they appear in your source code (even if the DOM was populated dynamically).

So, the following (non-jQuery) code:

```
var albums = document.getElementsByClassName('album_name');
var i=0;
for (i=0;i<albums.length;i++) {
    doSomethingWithAlbumName(albums[i].value);
}
```

would process each `.album_name` input in the correct order.  I'm not sure if that's what was being asked; if you just wanted to guarantee the order in which console.log prints out the properties of an object, that's not possible.

Comment: I should add, the HTMLCollection object returned from getElementsByClassName() is live-- it can change if the contents of the document change